# Theorem for finitely generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

A theorem in my notes states that given a field $K$, let $M$ be a left finitely generated $K[T]$-module; then $M$ is a torsion module if, and only if, $\dim_K(M)<\infty$.

However I consider the regular $\Bbb C-$module, which is finitely generated ($\{1\}$ generates $M$) and has dimension $2$ on $\Bbb R$ ($\{1,i\}$ spans $M$): then $M$ should be a torsion module but clearly no elements of $M$ is of torsion, so I must be wrong somewhere above. Thank you :)

Comment: still, $\mathbb{C}$ is not a polynomial ring

Answer (score 2):

$K[T]$ is the polynomial ring with formal variable $T$, $\mathbb{R}[\sqrt{3}]=\mathbb{R}$ is not an example. Suppose $M$ is finite dimensional over $K$. Then the map
$$\Phi: K[T] \rightarrow \text{Hom}_K(M,M)$$
given by sending $p \in K[T]$ to the action map by $p$
$$m \mapsto p \cdot m$$ 
is linear (check this). Since $M$ is finite dimensional, $\text{Hom}_K(M,M)$ is finite dimensional, so $\Phi$ cannot be injective since $K[T]$ is infinite dimensional as a $K$-vector space. So $\Phi$ has a nonzero element in its kernel, which annihilates every element in $M$, so certainly $M$ is a torsion module.
The other direction is as follows, suppose now $M$ is finitely generated by some finite set $\{a_1,..,a_n\}$ and $M$ is torsion. Then it follows that the set
$$A:=\{T^j(a_i) | i \in \{1,..,n\} j \geq 0 \}$$
generates $M$ as a vector space over $K$. But for each of the $a_i$, there is a $p \in K[T]$ not zero, such that 
$$p \cdot a_i =0.$$
Now try to prove that the $K$ span of the finite set
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{a_i, T(a_i),..,T^{j_i}(a_i)\}$$
contains the $K$ span of $A$, and thus generates $M$ as a $K$ vector space.

Comment: Sorry I made an edit

Comment: I have a solution for one direction and a problem with the other direction... I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: nvm I misread, there’s no problem with the other direction

Comment: So the mistake in my new question is that $\Bbb C$ is not omomorphic to $\Bbb R[T]$ basically

Comment: Well, yes. This exercise would even be a proof of that ;).

Comment: The normal argument for it would be that $\C$ is a field and no polynomial ring is a field.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What is meant is a torsion $K [ T ]$-module. In your example, $\mathbb C$ is indeed torsion over $\mathbb R [ T ]$, because $(T^2+1)\cdot 1 = 0$.

The statement is indeed correct, here's a strategy of proof :

If the dimension over $K$ is finite, for any $v\in M$, $K [ T ]\to M, P\mapsto P\cdot v$ cannot be injective, as $K [ T ]$ is infinite dimensional.

If it is finitely generated and torsion, you can find a finite generating family *over $K$* by taking the right amount of $T^i x$ for $x$ the generators.